# How To Fix Pixelated Cycles 3D Viewport Editor

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

When I use Cycles in the Viewport editor, the model is super pixelated. When watching tutorials, other people don't have that. My computer is high end enough to be able to handle it. What other settings could  I be missing?

[image]

**My Computer Specs:**

1. GeForce GTX1070
2. Intel Core i7-3770K CPU @ 3.5GHz
3. 16GB RAM

**My Blender Settings:**

1. Edit > Preferences > System > **CUDA > GeForce GTX1070 CHECKED**
2. Edit > Preferences > System > **CUDA > Intel Core i7-3770K CPU @ 3.5GHz UNCHECKED**
3. Edit > Preferences > System > Video Sequencer > **Memory Cache Limit > 10,000**
4. Edit > Preferences > System > Video Sequencer > **Cache Limit > 3,000**
5. Editor > Render Properties > **Render Engine > Cycles**
6. Editor > Render Properties > **Feature Set > Supported**
7. Editor > Render Properties > **Device > GPU Compute**
8. Editor > Render Properties > **Sampling > Viewport > 8 (Samples)**
9. Editor > Render Properties > **Light Paths > Max Bounces > Total > 6**

Comment: Just bump up the samples to 500+ and/or enable denoising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To echo [@brockmann (who commented)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/219215/how-to-fix-pixelated-cycles-3d-viewport-editor#comment370012_219215), eight samples is **very, very, very** low. If your graphics card is working with cycles render, I would at least use 512 samples and work from there.

Edit: I was unable to find questions on what samples are, so I guess I’ll explain it myself. A “sample” is one shot of data for rendering, and more shots mean better looking renders, just like more signal flares with more wind conditions will give you a better idea of where the ship is. In Cycles, a sample is a single ray of light, traced backwards out of a camera, through a pixel, hitting what it may until it gets to a light source, thus defining what color that pixel of the image should be. An “importance map” is made just before the rest of the rendering which maps out where lights are in the scene, so the backwards-traced rays will be more likely to go towards them and not oblivion. The blender manual at docs.blender.org explains it better, but basically, a light ray will bounce in an arbitrary direction if it hits a rough surface, and a more predictable direction if it hits a smooth one. Few samples will then return a lot of fuzz on rough objects. “Caustics” is another place where fuzz can be created, where light being bounced around by mirrors or glass can have a hard time finding a light source from the “importance map.” Thus, there is a lot of fuzz in your cube as only eight rays work on each pixel: it’s like calling eight random people in a country to find out how popular a TV show is. One set of eight might indicate no popularity, while another is more correct, while still another indicates that everyone watches that TV show. Lots of samples means lots of rays, lots of tested directions light could be coming from, and lots more actual representation of what kind of light is hitting that spot. More samples also means more computing time, but if you’ve got time for how long your computer (or GPU) takes, go ahead and do it.

NVidia is the best, so you can probably do a lot of samples

Comment: Low quality answer IMHO. At least a simple explanation why this is relevant, what path tracing actually is or a few supplementary links to previous Q&A's are needed to make this a good answer.

Comment: @brockmann Well, I could do those things, but I am kind of hoping that he already knows some of that. If he does ask further comment-questions on those subjects, I will indeed answer them, but I don’t want to over answer the question if he’s got what he needed (wear myself out).

Comment: I don't know what those are. Please make it an amazing answer for future noobies :)

Comment: @wongz oh, okay.  gotta do some other stuff right now, but will explain, and BGL do better next time. 

Comment: @wongz I hope that helps. You can also search for, “samples” or “denoising” or “caustics” or “raytracing” for more information. Check out the manual at docs.blender.org

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard Thanks! Appreciate it!